# Installation of mesa-18.1.4, stuck at "libtizcore"

Tags: software-installation, x-server, amd-graphics, mesa

I was trying to install another version of x-server, it needed lots of packages including mesa and it needed a lot of, too.
I installed over 15 packages... I found every package by googling and installed without any problems.

But I can not found "libtizcore" package. 
I am stuck at ./configure command.

> Package libtizcore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libtizcore.pc' to the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'libtizcore' found
>   checking for RADEON... yes configure: error: --enable-llvm is required
>   when building r300

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the message about "libtizcore".

The `./configure` command only stopped because it was going to create a MakeFile for the r300 driver, but you didn't have the `--enable-llvm` checked, which is needed to make it.

If you don't have `llvm` package installed (it says something about a `llvm-config` file being required) it means you don't have `llvm` installed.

A simple `sudo apt-get install llvm` will fix that.

Then rerun with the `--enable-llvm` flag on it:

`sudo ./configure --enable-llvm`

Answer (score 0):

Needs 3.9 version of llvm.

Try this.

```
# apt install llvm-3.9
# ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-config-3.9 /usr/bin/llvm-config
# ./configure --enable-llvm
```